# How to pass input to interactive command using ansible?

Tags: unix, ansible, command, yaml, expect

I have a command to execute on Unix server. The command expect user input at two points and then proceed further. The command is like follows:

```
$ abc_1.2_udate.bin /tmp/log

  Do you want to proceed y/n?
  y

  Please provide the credentials:
  1234
```

From ansible tried as follows:

```
  - name: execute the cmnd

    expect:

       Command: abc_1.2_udate.bin /tmp/log

       responses:

          Do you want to proceed y/n? "y"

          'Please provide the credentials:' "1234"
```

But the above piece does not work. Also I want to use expect module only for this.

Comment: Your example task is not a valid expect module call, neither a valid ansible task definition nor a valid yaml representation. Please review your playbook after reading the relevant docs/references, fix the obvious errors, run it again and eventually edit your question with the exact error message if you still have issues. `does not work` is never an accurate description of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change Command to command (C is not caps)
2. Responses should be given in quotes with the format `'Enter': "y"`

```
expect:
 command: abc_1.2_udate.bin /tmp/log
 responses:
  'Do you want to proceed y/n?': "y"
  'Please provide the credentials': "1234"
```